# matlab REGIONPROPS needs I as an input to calculate 'MinIntensity'

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I would like to know how to use the matlab function regionprops to perform pixel value measurements, according to the program's help this can be done using grayscale images as input to the function, however I have used the following code:

```
   A=imread('siluetagris.jpg');
   A=rgb2gray(A);
   imshow(A);impixelinfo;
   s=regionprops(A,'MaxIntensity');
   s.MaxIntensity
```

and I always get the following error:
      REGIONPROPS needs I as an input to
      calculate 'MinIntensity'

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) on region props. An image is not a valid input. You would need to first segment/label the image and region props would operate on the labels. If you simply want the maximum value of an image you should use `max(im(:))`

Comment: Here's what I tried after your comment:

    A=imread('siluetagris.jpg');
    A=im2bw(A);
    A=bwlabel(A);
    imshow(A==82);impixelinfo;

    s=regionprops(A,'MaxIntensity');
    s.MaxIntensity


This clearly segments the image using labels, but the output of the program is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
im=imread('peppers.png');
im=rgb2gray(im);
imbw=im2bw(im);
im_label=bwlabel(imbw);
s=regionprops(im_label,im,'MaxIntensity');
```

Note that in the documentation there is a section of pixel value measurements, these require both a label image and an intensity image to compute. After that example `s.MaxIntensity` should be an array with each value corresponding to the maximum intensity within that region.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your example, I changed it a little bit like this:im=imread('peppers.png');
im=rgb2gray(im);
imbw=im2bw(im); C=bwlabel(imbw),
s=regionprops(imbw,im,'MaxIntensity'); I did this because the documentation says: The first input to regionprops (BW,
    CC, or L) identifies the regions in I

Comment: You could also change `s=regionprops(imbw,im,'MaxIntensity');` to `s=regionprops(C,im,'MaxIntensity');` The labels are helpful in that they provide a unique identifier for each region. Updated answer to reflect.